# Draw balls from two bags, i need the expected value?

Tags: probability, expectation

Assume we have $2$ bags with $3$ colors balls, each bag has $n$ balls so $n/3$ of each color. if we take one ball from each bag then place them aside until we took them all, what is the expected value of the number of matching balls?
[bags setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWEqC.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  What is the chance the first pair matches?  Every pair has the same chance to match-imagine reordering the draws to bring each pair to the front.  Therefore the expected number of matches is ???

Comment: the chance of each pair is not the same, the drawing is dependent!

Comment: Yes it is the same.  Compute it by hand for $n=3$.  You will find the probability of matches is the same for each pair of balls.

Comment: Can you give me a more clear answer, I can't figure it out?

Comment: I found that the expected value= n/3.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Each ball has $1/3$ chance of matching and there are $n$ of them.